# Rego: Set comprehension undefined

Tags: set, opa, rego

I am trying to understand why the following examples on using set comprehension give different results:

1. https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/5x5mXmsyr0
2. https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/IVQlTYcVpD

In the first example, `rlt` is evaluated to an empty set despite `foo["c"]` is undefined. I expect `rlt` to also be undefined.

In the second example, I removed the function but directly set `rlt2` to the result of a set comprehension. This time it does return undefined.

Can someone explain the difference here?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you see here is the type checker doing the best it can.

The error you get, is because at compile time, the type checker knows which keys exist.
For the function call, `foo` is a function argument,

```
myFunc(foo) = rlt {
    rlt := {f | f := foo["c"]}
}
```

and the compiler cannot tell if `foo["c"]` exists or does not exist -- that depends on the actual call. You might define the function like that, but use it in other ways like

```
$ echo '{"c": 123}' | opa eval -I -d policy.rego 'data.play.myFunc(input)'
```

So it doesn't do any kind of deeper flow analysis.

Now `rlt` is not undefined because set (object, array) comprehensions are never undefined -- if their bodies are always undefined, the overall collection becomes an empty set (object, array).